# ie9 border disappears when zoomed out

Tags: internet-explorer-9

I have a 1px border around some images. Ive only seen this issue in IE9 but when you zoom out some sides of the border disappear. Is this a bug or just how IE9 zooms out? Using the developer toolbar it doesn't seem to happen on IE8 and 7. Thanks